# How to allow user select and copy text with jstree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jstree

I'm using jstree to build a treeview, with a very basic configuration:

```
$('container').jstree({
  "core": { "html_titles": true },
  "plugins": ["themes", "html_data"],
  "themes": {
     "theme": "default"
  }
});
```

But when user passes mouse over any node, cursor changes to hand and there's no way to select whatever text is on node, **at least on IE10**. My users might need to copy some of contents, so I wish to let him/her select text, double-click on a word, etc. This is query-only treeview, I don't need any particular action on clicking, and it's ok to open/close nodes using the left button.

**UPDATE:**

After some time, I decided to drop jstree in favor of a manually-built treeview. It was easiest than I thought, specially because my treeview was only for query purposes (don't need to allow select nodes, don't need do add, remove or edit nodes, and all nodes are ready at page start). To open and close nodes, I use jQuery [slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) and [slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/).

I will let this question open. Might be useful to someone.

Comment: User can still select the text right? eventhough the cursor is showing hand

Comment: Nope, at least on IE10.

Comment: I have this problem also, could you please post the code for your manual tree view